# How to solve an equation for a given variable in R?

Tags: r, math, differential-equations

This is equation `a <- x * t - 2 * x`. I want to solve this equation for `t`.
So basically, set `a = 0` and solve for `t` . I am new to the `R` packages for solving equations. I need the package that solves for complex roots. The original equations I am work with have real and imaginary roots. I am looking for an algebraic solution only, not numerical.

I tried:

```
a <- x * t - 2 * x
solve(a,t)
```

I run into an error:

```
Error in solve.default(a, t) : 'a' (1000 x 1) must be square
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible: [mre]

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "solve"? Numerics or algebra?

Comment: I should clarify I want to solve it with algebra

Comment: The solution is `t=2`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Ryacas` to get the solution as an expression of `x`:

```
library(Ryacas)

x <- Sym("x")
t <- Sym("t")

Solve(x*t-2*x == 0, t)
# Yacas vector:
# [1] t == 2 * x/x
```

As you can see, the solution is `t=2` (assuming `x` is not zero).

Let's try a less trivial example:

```
Solve(x*t-2*x == 1, t)
# Yacas vector:
# [1] t == (2 * x + 1)/x
```

If you want to get a function which provides the solution as a function of `x`, you can do:

```
solution <- Solve(x*t-2*x == 1, t)
f <- function(x){}
body(f) <- yacas(paste0("t Where ", solution))$text
f
# function (x) 
# (2 * x + 1)/x
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for optimize:

```
a=function(x,t) x*t-2*x
optimize(a,lower=-100,upper=100,t=10)
optimize(a,lower=-100,upper=100,x=2)
```

If you need more help, I need a reproductible example.

Comment: Thank you, this is a helpful equation to know. I needed to find when the equation crosses zero and I was able to just square the equation for the optimize to find the solution